# How does the computer detect the routers Around?

Tags: router, modem

I can see any wireless modem around(networks) in internet access icon , How routers say to my computer "hey I am here ?"
is it port forwarding ? upnp ? IGMP ?  which protocol they send and in what port?
How can I see those packet in wireshark?
If I can see the packet dose it mean I can find their IP?

the protocols I mention was the first thing come in my mind because I think somehow  they can be used for this action

Comment: Routers do not. WAPs do as part of the 82.11 standard.

Answer (score 2):

Wireless access points transmit periodic [beacon frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_frame#:%7E:text=Beacon%20frame%20is%20one%20of,members%20of%20the%20service%20set.) to announce the presence of wireless networks.

Answer (score 1):

WAPs send beacon frames to the STAs, and the STAs can send probe frames. This is all part of the 802.11 standard used by Wi-Fi.

Remember that the protocols you are referring to are layer-3 or above protocols, but 802.11 defines the physical (layer-1) and data-link (layer-2) protocols.